# Using importune

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I am learning the meaning and usage of 'importune'. I came to know that mostly the word takes the form 'importune someone'. But there a couple of statements I do not understand regarding it.

1. After a year of being importuned, dad let me have the car.

Why couldn't we use the following statement:
        After a year of importuning, dad let me have the car.

2. He was left with their infant daughter, their rural home, the night sky, importuning memories, and a gaping chasm.

Semantically, what does 'importuning memories' mean here?

Comment: Memories nagging at his conscience.

Comment: citing your dictionary finding is helpful

Comment: These are very different questions, gemspark. Although 'importune' is rare anyway, 'After a year of importuning, dad ...' at least strongly suggests that it had been _dad_ doing the importuning. // 'importuning memories', as @Zebrafish says, is probably meant to mean aching, nagging memories, but whether culpability (conscience) or just sadness is involved can't be deduced. I'd say it's a poor choice, because importune means _nag in an attempt to get someone to do something_. Using such an uncommon word in such an unusual  metaphorical way isn't advisable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The second statement is from the 'Slate', so I felt it should be correct. That's why I asked.

Comment: The whole article sounds rather high-flown (but that's my _opinion_).

Comment: There’s no relevant difference between your “being importuned” and “importuning…”.

“importuning memories” means either “nagging memories” or that the author was most concerned with demonstrating his ability…

Broadly, I'd support Edwin's "high-flown".